# Passing environment variables to node.js using pm2

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I am trying to pass some arguments to my Express application which is run by pm2. There wasn't any hint in their documentation to do so, but apparently it's possible to pass some EV to your node application like `SOME_STUFF=xxx pm2 start app.js`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's actually possible and I'm pretty sure it was in PM2's documentation some time ago.

Anyways, that's what you need to do:

```
pm2 start app.js -- -some_stuff xxx
```

Basically, add `--` and then you can add your own app parameters.

Managed to find the source, it was hidden quite well: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#42-ways-of-starting-processes

Comment: Wierd, this doesn't work for me. but ```SOME_STUFF=xxx pm2 start app.js ``` worked. Any thoughts why ?

Comment: @Andrius thanks a lot. spent two hours trying different methods, luckily ended up here.

Comment: Just confirming that using " -- " resolved my issue loading Azure App Service ENV variables to PM2 from a custom container.  This is vital to include....

Answer (score 32):

Note - after updating environment variables in your environment, you must do the following:

`pm2 restart all --update-env`

ask me how I know...

Edit: also look for a .env file in the node source directory...

Comment: Beautiful, solved an issue I've been trying to figure out for an hour

Answer (score 11):

The environment variables don't always update unless you force them to.

```
SOME_STUFF=xxx pm2 start app.js --update-env
```

Answer (score 10):

I was having issues passing parameters using `pm2 start app.js -- -some_stuff xxx` so I opted to do this instead: `SOME_STUFF=xxx OTHER_STUFF=abc pm2 start app.js`.

Then when I ran `pm2 logs` I was able to see that my app successfully started and that the environment variables were set correctly where as before I was seeing errors around these variables when I ran `pm2 logs`.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass ENV in ecosystem.config.js

*ecosystem.config.js (in the root)*

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "project-name",
      exec_mode: "cluster",
      instances: "1",
      script: "./server/index.js", // your script
      args: "start",
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: "production", 
        SOME_ENV: "some_value"...
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

In the console:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

There is information [about configuration of ENV](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/) in PM2 official documentation

Comment: can i just load a .env and .env.local somehow?

Comment: I needed to run pm2 start ecosystem.config.js, instead of pm2 run ...

Answer (score 1):

My node app (sveltekit build) starts in my ubuntu server when I use

```
node build/index.js
```

and includes enviroment variables

so with pm2 I found that my app starts with envs starting it:

```
pm2 "node build/index.js"
```