# Read command line arguments passed to node.js using pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm aware about how to pass variables to node.js using pm2. But how do I read them?  `process.argv` doesn't contain it.

This is what I'm referring to.

[Passing environment variables to node.js using pm2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656947/passing-environment-variables-to-node-js-using-pm2)

**UPDATE**

`pm2 start file_name.js --  -my_port 8080` is the right way to do it. `process.argv` will contain the arguments.

**But** running `pm2 describe file_name` still shows args -3000 which is a cached value.
Restarting the system gives me the argument that was passed last before restart, which was 3000 in my case.

Comment: Please provide a sample of how you are passing variables.

Comment: Here it is

pm2 start fetch.js -- -port 80

Comment: Deleting the process and restarting didn't help either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're confusing :

- `node_args`

> node_args list    ["--harmony", "--max-stack-size=1024"]  arguments given to node when it is launched

Those are `node` executable options, like `--harmony` or `--debug=7001`. For more informations see `node --help`

- `args`

> args  list    ["--enable-logs", "-n", "15"]   arguments given to your app when it is launched

Those are your script arguments. In a json declaration it's the `arg` property but within command line the syntax is:

```
pm2 start app.js -- arg1 arg2
```

Those should be available in `process.argv`.

[Reference](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#list-of-attributes-available)

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit confused. It's the command line arguments that I want to pass.

After running the following command

pm2 start fetch.js --  -port 3000 

I got this in process.argv

[ '/usr/bin/nodejs',
  '/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/FetchFork.js',
  '-port',
  '80' ]

Comment: Port 80 is what I had passed as an argument yesterday. So clearly there is some kind of caching going on here.

Comment: Yes once the process is in memory arguments might stay the same. Restart it with new arguments if it's already started.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Node.js doc about `process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv):

> An array containing the command line arguments.

It does not contain environment variables. You can access the `ENV_VARIABLE` environment variable using

```
process.env.ENV_VARIABLE
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4870450/810830).